# Matplotlib.collections.PathCollection

Tags: python, matplotlib

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pl3D4SosO_4&list=PL9mhv0CavXYjiIniCLj_5KKN58PaxJBVj&index=2

Right at time stamp 2:13.

I am trying to follow a youtube tutorial and I have hit a road block. There is no documentation online that tells me how to implement matplotlib.collections.PathCollection

The youtuber in this video that I am following runs the first bit of his code (at about 2:13) and a plot appears with some color data points. Above this plot it says <matplotlib.collections.PathCollection at 0x208cd62cef0>

If anyone could tell me how this youtuber got this plot to appear I would be forever grateful.

I have found documentation for matplotlib.collections, but zero information on how it is used, I asked the youtuber how he got to this point in the comments and am waiting on an answer.

Thank you Craig, I am adding the code that doesn't work for me here

EDIT:
(I have been attempting this in a pycharm IDE and the video is using Jupyter, idk if that makes a difference)

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import plyplot as plt
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs

X,y = make_blobs(n_samples = 500, centers = 5, random_state = 3)

plt.figure(0)
plt.grid(True)
plt.scatter(X[:,0], X[:,1],c=y)
```

when this is run in the video a plot with color clusters appears.

Maybe I should be trying this in jupyter, maybe some image libraries are pre-loaded there?

Comment: You have a much better chance of getting an answer if you post the code that you are using and explain what isn't working.

Comment: If you are using Jupyter, the result of the last executed command in a cell is printed out as text. This can be helpful for debugging, but can also be confusing. A trick to suppress that output is adding a semicolon after the last line in the cell. Many matplotlib functions return the elements they created, just in case you want to make manual changes. Usually this can be ignored.

Comment: Also note that in Jupyter, you usually need to add `%matplotlib inline` near the start of your code if you want to see the plot inline. This depends on how Jupyter is installed and configured.

Comment: I have edited my post, added the code involved. Also, I realized that the video and I are using different IDEs, unsure if that makes a difference

Comment: Jupyter is an interactive environment so plots are generated when you run a cell and show up inline. The plot should also appear for you when you run it in Pycharm, but it will probably pop up in a separate window. When you run this code in Pycharm (Shift-F10), what does it do?

Comment: Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: You will need to add `plt.show()` at the end of your program to make the graph appear.

Comment: no errors thrown. Also, I installed scikit-learn instead of sklearn beacuse it wouldn't install on pycharm. Before it threw a "no module sklearn" error. sorry I can't go back and copy the exact error message now that scikit-learn has been installed.

Comment: Craig, that's what I needed. the exact chart the youtuber had just appeared for me! thank you.  One last stack overflow question, should I now click the "answer your question" button to say that my question was answered?

Comment: I've added this solution as an answer that you should be able to accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jupyter is a special interactive environment and it automatically renders matplotlib plots when it runs a cell that creates a plot. If you are doing the same thing in an IDE, then you will need to explicitly render the plot by calling `plt.show()` when you want the plot to appear. You can do this for your code by adding it to the end:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import plyplot as plt
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs

X,y = make_blobs(n_samples = 500, centers = 5, random_state = 3)

plt.figure(0)
plt.grid(True)
plt.scatter(X[:,0], X[:,1],c=y)
plt.show()  # <-- show the plot
```